# Setting an Attribute as a "string" or null in JSON Schema with a maxLength

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm trying to create a JSON schema that allows for a nullable attribute. For example, I want the following JSON to be valid:

```
{
 "some_name" : null
}
```

with the following schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "some_name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        null
      ],
      "maxLength": 100
    }
  }
}
```

However, it's invalid as it thinks that "null" can't have a maxLength. Is there a good way to do this? I wish there was a "nullable" attribute, or something of the sort!

Comment: I think "null" is its own type (in quotes, i.e., `"type": "null"`), and therefore you need to specify the `maxLength` for the string type and allow multiple types.  Possibly with `oneOf`, `anyOf`, or an `enum`?  I've never used it.  Just did a quick google search.

Comment: I've never used it either (or JSON Schema in general) so I'm a bit out of touch. Any extra info helpful at all, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like making the type `"null"` instead of `null`, in my SCHEMA does the trick. Null is it's own schema-type, and seems to trigger better validation.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "some_name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ],
      "maxLength": 100
    }
  }
}
```